# Merge e2fsck and fsck

Tags: discussion, tags

Just noticed there is both a [e2fsck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e2fsck) and a (much larger) [fsck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fsck) tag.

Is there any reason these shouldn't be merged?  There might be questions that are specifically about e2fsck, but they are just as likely to get tagged fsck and that level of specificity seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I think just retag them and let [e2fsck](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e2fsck) die. They're not really synonyms; just e2fsck is a subset of fsck. Not to mention a synonym is hardly worth it for two questions.